# Find all pairs of elements in an array such that the absolute value of their difference is x

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an unsorted array and I want to find all pairs in that array such that their difference (in absolute value) gives the x.

For example if x=8 and we have array {13, 1,-8, 21, 0, 9,-54, 17, 31, 81,-46} I would get:
Indices 0 & 3 with values 13 & 21 (e.g., 13-21= | 8 |)
Indices 1 & 5 with values 1 & 9
Indices 2 & 4 with values -8 & 0
Indices 6 & 10 with values -54 & -46

I made a solution but I'm not sure if it is O(n) or O(n^2). I tried to avoid a nested loop and instead keep two pointers i and j, but I still think it is O(n^2)? It kind of behaves like a nested loop.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 1;

    System.out.println("All pairs of elements of the array that subtract exactly to absolute value of " + x + " are:");

    while (i < A.length && j < A.length)
    {
        if (abs(A[i] - A[j]) == x)
        {
            System.out.println("Indices " + i + " & " + j + " with values " + A[i] + " & " + A[j]);
        }

        if (j != A.length - 1)
        {
            j++;
        } else if (i == A.length - 1)
        {
            return;
        } else
        {
            i++;
            j = i + 1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try posting it on [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Print out the values of `i` and `j` for your code, and for a nested loop. If the outputs are the same (as I expect they are) then you have your answer: your code is O(n^2). To do better than O(n^2), you need a different algorithm, e.g. sort the array first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Assuming that the code works correctly, you might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Answer (score 0):

> It kind of behaves like a nested loop

It's not just "kind of" -- you've hand-coded two loops, with the **j**-loop logically inside **i**-loop.  The critical parts are:

```
i = 0
while i < limit {
    ...
    i += 1
}
```

and

```
j = 1
while j < limit {
    ...
    j = i+1
}
```

Each of these is the "while"-ish version of a **for** loop.

This, combined with your if-else logic, translates pretty well to

```
for i in 0 : limit {
    for j in i+1 : limit {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use map to index your array values, then calculate the complement of target value, and search the complement's index in map, which is O(1) and inserting values into map is O(n), so the time complexity can be reduced to O(1), the code snippet is shown below

import java.util.*;

public class TwoDiff {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int arr[] = {13, 1,-8, 21, 0, 9,-54, 17, 31, 81,-46};
    int target = 8;
    List<int[]> res = twoDiff(arr, target);
    res.forEach(l -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l)));
}

private static List<int[]> twoDiff(int[] arr, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<int[]> resList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
    {
        map.put(arr[i], i);
    }
    for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int complement = arr[i] - target;
        if(map.containsKey(complement))
        {
            resList.add(new int[] {i, map.get(complement)});
        }
    }
    return  resList;
}
```

}